# How to update sharepoint project from .net 3.5 to 4.0

Tags: asp.net, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0, sharepoint-2010

I need to change the .NET Framework Version of my Sharepoint Project from 3.5 to 4.0.

The project is generated with VisualStudio2010, Sharepoint version is also 2010. I already found [this](http://www.infosysblogs.com/microsoft/2010/05/sharepoint_2010_and_net_framew.html) blogpost regarding this topic, but it doesnt work.

.NET 4.0 is installed on the development machine but I'm not able to select the framework in the target-framework tab at the project settings:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SharePoint 2010 does not support .NET 4.0.

If you really have to connect a .NET 4.0 application to SharePoint, you can use a web service to communicate. But you won't be able to write a .NET 4.0 WebPart or a similar SharePoint artifact.